# How is the vertical distribution of water vapor changing?

Tags: climate-change, climate, water, climate-models, atmospheric-chemistry

In this [publication about data assimilation and observations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-74703-1) (paywall alert) in the chapter General Concepts in Meteorology and Dynamics (by Andrew Charlton-Perez, William Lahoz, Richard Swinbank, Pages 325-349), while being a decade old, it is stated that the water vapour mixing ratio tendency in the stratosphere is positive according to sounding from Boulder, Colorado and negative according to UARS HALOE instrument and under research. I tried to google more resent research, but didn't get to a clear conclusion.

I would assume that the variability would emerge from the temperature changes in different layers of the atmosphere; warming levels would be able to hold more water vapour and vice versa (Clausius-Clapeyron equation for water vapour).

**What is the current understanding of the water vapour mixing ratio changes in time in different heights of the atmosphere?**